# WP7 Extras Menu, What is it for?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find out about the Extras menu on windows phone. Extras.xml. Here is what I've found (there isn't much out there)

1. Adding extras.xml to your app will put it into the 'extras menu'
2. Extras menu is available in your media library
3. you can send media to your app via extras menu

What else is this used for? Where else can it go? Can you use extras menu in your app or is it an OS only menu? Is it limited to media?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Extras in order to further integrate your app into the OS. For example, a user can view a picture from the Pictures Hub. If your app uses the `Extras` file, then it'll appear as an option from within the Pictures Hub. The user can then tap on your app (from the picture's menu) and your app will launch, with the OS passing the picture to your app as a parameter. Your app reads in the image and performs some sort of function on it. Using the `Extras` file is very easy as demonstrated on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817010%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

The `Mango` update will further enhance this by providing the `Extras` menu from within Bing search results. The demo shown recently showed the user searching for a movie in Bing. Straight from the results, the user can launch the `IMDB` app (or any other app that uses `Extras`) and have the system automatically send in the details of the movie they searched for. Within the IMDB app, they could see trailers, info etc...

Comment: you've told me what I already know, but it sounds like your saying they are expanding it to be used in other areas, not just photos. So it's used by the OS (and OS apps) then, not by other apps?

Comment: I get it now, at the bottom of that link I see some images. It's the same thing android has when you hold an image. I just installed DropBox and it was added to the android extras menu so you can send the image to dropbox. Thanks.

Comment: The point of it is to allow your app to be launched from within the hubs. Although `Photos` is the supported hub at the moment, they will be expanding it to others. Yes, in its current form, it's only used by the OS in the sense that it'll only appear in `Extras` menus which is a menu not available to third party apps.